# Crop image maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: android, crop, aspect-ratio

This is the following code to crop the image I'm using:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mOutputX = display.getWidth();  
    mOutputY = display.getHeight();

    chooseImage.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", mOutputX);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", mOutputY);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", mOutputX);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", mOutputY);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Utils.newImageFile(getApplicationContext()));
            intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());
            intent.putExtra("setWallpaper", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);                
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This code works perfectly on my ICS device (Nexus S); the copping rectangle mantains the display proportions (intent.putExtra("aspectX", mOutputX); intent.putExtra("aspectY", mOutputY);) and the output format of the image is resized to the display resolution to have reduced size.

But on an adroid 2.3.3 device (Wildfire S) the cropping rectangle is a square and doesn't mantain the display with/height proportion. The output format on other hand is the right one (320x480).